# Is debugging a termbox-go using program with VSCode and Delve possible?

Tags: go, terminal, visual-studio-code, delve

I'm trying to create a console application using https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go/. As editor, I'm using VSCode with the Go plugin and Delve for debugging.

Now the issue is that when I start debugging, I don't see the termbox output in the integrated console window. But I'm looking for quite a bit now and still couldn't find a way to start the program in an external terminal window yet. Is there one?

Are there alternatives I'm overlooking (maybe a `launch.json` setting I didn't find)? How can I debug this application that will depend on user input and interaction with VSCode as my editor, if at all possible?

Here is a small example file:

```
package main

import "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"

func main() {
    initTermbox()
    defer termbox.Close()

    eventQueue := make(chan termbox.Event)
    go func() {
        for {
            eventQueue <- termbox.PollEvent()
        }
    }()

    mainLoop(eventQueue)
}

func mainLoop(eventQueue chan termbox.Event) {
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case ev := <-eventQueue:
            if ev.Type == termbox.EventKey && ev.Key == termbox.KeyEsc {
                break loop
            }
            if ev.Key == termbox.KeyArrowDown {
                termbox.SetCell(1, 3, 'X', termbox.ColorRed, termbox.ColorDefault)
                termbox.Flush()
            }
        }
    }
}

func initTermbox() {
    err := termbox.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm running into the exact same scenario.

Comment: @StuartThompson Unfortunately not. I did find an open issue on the termbox-go github though. The developer doesn't seem to be using delve.

Comment: any updates yet?